# Get total for unique items from Map in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I currently have a map which stores the following information:

```
Map<String,String> animals= new HashMap<String,String>();
animals.put("cat","50");
animals.put("bat","38");
animals.put("dog","19");
animals.put("cat","31");
animals.put("cat","34");
animals.put("bat","1");
animals.put("dog","34");
animals.put("cat","55");
```

I want to create a new map with total for unique items in the above map. So in the above sample, count for cat would be 170, count for bat would be 39 and so on.

I have tried using Set to find unique animal entries in the map, however, I am unable to get the total count for each unique entry

Comment: You currently have a map with one "cat" and one "dog". `HashMap` doesn't allow duplicate keys.

Comment: Explaining further what @Guy said: each time you use `put` in a map, and the key was already there, that `put` replaces the value that was in the map for that key. The whole point of a map is that a key is unique and you can look the data up using only the key.

Comment: I see, Tried to print the animals map and see what @Guy and RealSkeptic are saying. Let me try dimo414's solution to see if that works

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `String` for arithmetic, use `int` or `double` (or `BigInteger`/`BigDecimal`, but that's probably overkill here). I'd suggest making your map a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Second, `Map.put()` will *overwrite* the previous value if the given key is already present in the map, so as @Guy points out your map actually only contains `{cat:55, dog:34, bat:1}`. You need to get the previous value somehow in order to preserve it.

The classic way (pre-Java-8) is like so:

```
public static void putOrUpdate(Map<String, Integer> map, String key, int value) {
  Integer previous = map.get(key);
  if (previous != null) {
    map.put(key, previous + value);
  } else {
    map.put(key, value);
  }
}
```

Java 8 adds a number of useful methods to [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to make this pattern easier, like [`Map.merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) which does the put-or-update for you:

```
map.merge(key, value, (p, v) -> p + v);
```

You may also find that a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) is a better data structure to use as it handles incrementing/decrementing for you; Guava provides [a nice implementation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multiset).

Answer (score 0):

As Guy said. Now you have one bat, one dog and one cat. Another 'put's will override your past values. For definition. Map stores key-value pairs where each key in map is unique. If you have to do it by map you can sum it just in time. For example, if you want to add another value for cat and you want to update it you can do it in this way:

```
animals.put("cat", animals.get("cat") + yourNewValue);
```

Your value for cat will be updated. This is for example where our numbers are float/int/long, not string as you have. If you have to do it by strings you can use in this case:

```
animals.put("cat", Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(animals.get("cat")) + yourNewValue));
```

However, it's ugly. I'd recommend create

```
Map<String, Integer> animals = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```